# Parsing a list into a map

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm getting the following back from `plug` `conn.req_headers:

```
[
  {"accept",
   "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"},
  {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"},
  {"accept-language", "en-GB,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8"},
  {"cache-control", "max-age=0"},
  {"connection", "keep-alive"},
  {"cookie",
   "_xsrf=2|353a732a|e6f0e245b4f4617b78f5080f716b5a83|1548858283; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1548926887|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MjlmNjg1MmMwMTA5NGZlNjllM2FmNzg0YmFlMDM4ZTY=|b5777f2478a76e40e5d2a194c35a6dc49771b5522513299099e9baf47d7c0975\"; _shortr_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAABbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYcnEvMWJQRE1OSVROSG1JOXRDY1VrUT09.SAlNvN6U9ol3ldsUP2qjlVXTJgvtLdSUzjBkAuuW5NM"},
  {"host", "localhost:4000"},
  {"referer", "http://localhost:4000/links"},
  {"upgrade-insecure-requests", "1"},
  {"user-agent",
   "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.81 Safari/537.36"}
]
```

I need to convert it to a Map (to send to ecto), such that %{"accept" => "...", ...}

In python I'd do something like

```
{v[0]: v[1] for v in original_list}
```

Is there something so beautiful in Elixir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Enum#into/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/2):

> Inserts the given enumerable into a collectable.

For example (see docs for more examples):

```
iex> [{"foo", "bar"}, {"fizz"}, {"buzz"}] |> Enum.into(%{})
%{"foo" => "bar", "fizz" => "buzz"}
```

In your case:

```
iex(1)> [             
...(1)>   {"accept",
...(1)>    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"},
...(1)>   {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"},
...(1)>   {"accept-language", "en-GB,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8"},
...(1)>   {"cache-control", "max-age=0"},
...(1)>   {"connection", "keep-alive"},
...(1)>   {"cookie",
...(1)>    "_xsrf=2|353a732a|e6f0e245b4f4617b78f5080f716b5a83|1548858283; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1548926887|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MjlmNjg1MmMwMTA5NGZlNjllM2FmNzg0YmFlMDM4ZTY=|b5777f2478a76e40e5d2a194c35a6dc49771b5522513299099e9baf47d7c0975\"; _shortr_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAABbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYcnEvMWJQRE1OSVROSG1JOXRDY1VrUT09.SAlNvN6U9ol3ldsUP2qjlVXTJgvtLdSUzjBkAuuW5NM"},
...(1)>   {"host", "localhost:4000"},
...(1)>   {"referer", "http://localhost:4000/links"},
...(1)>   {"upgrade-insecure-requests", "1"},
...(1)>   {"user-agent",
...(1)>    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.81 Safari/537.36"}
...(1)> ] |> Enum.into(%{})
%{
  "accept" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
  "accept-encoding" => "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language" => "en-GB,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8",
  "cache-control" => "max-age=0",
  "connection" => "keep-alive",
  "cookie" => "_xsrf=2|353a732a|e6f0e245b4f4617b78f5080f716b5a83|1548858283; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1548926887|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MjlmNjg1MmMwMTA5NGZlNjllM2FmNzg0YmFlMDM4ZTY=|b5777f2478a76e40e5d2a194c35a6dc49771b5522513299099e9baf47d7c0975\"; _shortr_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAABbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYcnEvMWJQRE1OSVROSG1JOXRDY1VrUT09.SAlNvN6U9ol3ldsUP2qjlVXTJgvtLdSUzjBkAuuW5NM",
  "host" => "localhost:4000",
  "referer" => "http://localhost:4000/links",
  "upgrade-insecure-requests" => "1",
  "user-agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.81 Safari/537.36"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Map.new`

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/1

```
iex> [{"foo", "bar"}, {"fizz", "buzz"}] |> Map.new
%{"fizz" => "buzz", "foo" => "bar"}
```